# Matlab to OpenCV: mask of pixels with value inside a range

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, computer-vision

I have this Matlab code to find a mask (`skin`) of the pixel with values inside the ranges for H and S channels of my HSV image `hsv_im`:

```
h_range = [0.02 0.085]; 
s_range = [0.18 .754];

H = hsv_im(:,:,1);
S = hsv_im(:,:,2);

%targets skin by only selecting values within the rectangle skin range
skin = (S>s_range(1) & S<s_range(2) & H>h_range(1) & H<h_range(2));
```

I need to port this to OpenCV. So far I have this:

```
  float h_range[2] = {0.02, 0.085};
  float s_range[2] = {0.18, 0.754};

  vector<Mat> channels;
  split(imageHSV, channels);
  Mat H = channels[0];
  Mat S = channels[1];
```

but I failed to do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `imageHSV` has values in range `[0,1]`, otherwise you just need to change the range values. This is because in Matlab images are usually in range [0,1], while in OpenCV in range [0,255].

Actually for HSV images this is a little different:

- If `imageHSV` is of type `CV_8UC3`, then the ranges are: `H` in [0,180], `S` and `V` in [0,255].
- If `imageHSV` is of type `CV_32FC3`, the valid ranges for OpenCV are: `H` in [0,360], `S` and `V` in [0,1].

---

You can do this using [inRange](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange). Just define lower and upper range for the 3 channels. Take care to correct the Matlab range for OpenCV:

```
Mat imgHSV = ... type should CV_32FC3

Mat skin;
inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(0.02, 0.18, 0), Scalar(0.085, 0.754, 1), skin);
//                      h     s    v            h      s    v
//                      lower range              upper range

// skin will be a binary mask of type CV_8UC1, with values either 0 or 255
```